# Insert child node in nltk tree

Tags: python, tree, nltk

Assuming that I can read and edit all tree's leaves labels, using the following code:

```
for leaf in t.treepositions('leaves'):
  t[leaf] = new_value
```

How could I add a new leaf as a child of the actual leaf t[leaf]? Could be a silly question, but I haven't lot of experience with nltk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you bound to using the treepositions method? If not; if you just loop through all subtrees of your tree (recursively if needed), you can insert something at any point (an nltk tree is actually 'just' a list representation).

Here's an example that addes a modifier to a VP (for no apparant reason :)):

```
import nltk
t = nltk.tree.Tree.fromstring("(S (NP I) (VP (V saw) (NP him)))")
print(t)
for index, st in enumerate(t.subtrees()):
    if st.label() == 'VP':
        st.insert(index, nltk.tree.Tree('ADV', ['yesterday']))
print(t)
```

Output:

```
(S (NP I) (VP (V saw) (NP him)))
(S (NP I) (VP (V saw) (NP him) (ADV yesterday)))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes! Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for. I have another related question: can I add a subtree in a generic position? Let's take your example, and let's say for instance to add a subtree on the left of (V saw), always as a child of VP (so I want to add a left_sibling to the "saw" node). Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, just change the position of the insert statement (I cheated a bit by inserting at the index of my enumerate loop, but the insertion was on the subtree, it just so happened to be correct in this case). Modify the insert line to look like this to insert to the left of the verb: st.insert(0, nltk.tree.Tree('ADV', ['just']))